# Commas in Tag Cloud

Tags: php, theme-development, themes, tags

Using `<?php wp_tag_cloud(''); ?>` to display tags on my website, how do I separate each tag with a comma but also remove the comma from the last tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Wordpress Codex on tag clouds](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud), you need to specify a comma as the "separator" argument.

```
$args = "separator"=>",";
wp_tag_cloud($args);
```

Comment: where would I enter that though?

Comment: @JoeBobby If I understand what you want to do, you can create your own [wordpress widget](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-create-wordpress-widgets/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Filter the seperator arg for the tag cloud function. Put the following in your theme's functions.php

/**
 * Filter arguments of tag cloud widget to enlarge our text and
 * add commas
 */
function myfunc_filter_tag_cloud($args) {
    $args['smallest'] = 18;
    $args['largest'] = 32;
    $args['unit'] = 'px';
    $args['separator']= ', ';
    return $args;
}
add_filter ( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'myfunc_filter_tag_cloud');
```

Comment: it didnt work could you paste in a code block?